# json validator complains this parse error

Tags: json

I have this json:

```
{'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'bool': {'should': [{'term': {'sld': 'domaintools'}}, {'match': {'sld': 'domaintools'}}, {'match': {'sld': 'domaintool'}}, {'match': {'sld': 'clomaintools'}}, {'match': {'sld': 'c1omaintools'}}, {'match': {'sld': 'c10maintools'}}, {'match': {'sld': 'c1onaintools'}}, {'match': {'sld': 'c1ornaintools'}}, ...}
```

I have to remove the rest of this json since it exceeds the words limit, and json validator complains the error occurs on the first line, as bellow:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1: {'query': {'bool': {' -^ Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

This is a bit hard to see and I don't know where this json is wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All string has to be surrounded by double quotes in JSON.

When the object is closed up correctly and all single quotes is replaces with double quotes, you get following JSON object, which is valid:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "bool":{
                  "should":[
                     {
                        "term":{
                           "sld":"domaintools"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match":{
                           "sld":"domaintools"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match":{
                           "sld":"domaintool"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match":{
                           "sld":"clomaintools"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match":{
                           "sld":"c1omaintools"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match":{
                           "sld":"c10maintools"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match":{
                           "sld":"c1onaintools"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match":{
                           "sld":"c1ornaintools"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```